# Real-time operating via Python

Tags: python, real-time

So I am an inexperienced Python coder, with what I have gathered might be a rather complicated need. I am a cognitive scientist and I need precise stimulus display and button press detection. I have been told that the best way to do this is by using real-time operating, but have no idea how to go about this. Ideally, with each trial, the program would operate in real-time, and then once the trial is over, the OS can go back to not being as meticulous. There would be around 56 trials. Might there be a way to code this from my python script?

(Then again, all I need to know is when a stimulus is actually displayed. The real-time method would assure me that the stimulus is displayed when I want it to be, a top-down approach. On the other hand, I could take a more bottom-up approach if it is easier to just know to record when the computer actually got a chance to display it.)

Comment: Displaying images and reacting to button clicks is really fast on today's computers, even for "normal" GUI applications.  I assume that human reaction time is by magnitudes larger than GUI event reaction time.  Are you sure that you need extra precision?

Comment: Yeah, I'm sure. The effects I'm expecting to see are hovering at 45 ms. Sure, every little thing is "fast enough" but enough "fast enoughs" might compile to create or mask an effect.

Comment: Other things going on at the same time can still cause multiple millisecond latency jitter, which might be too much for many purposes, even when measuring human responses (because they reduce accuracy too much). Unfortunately, this can't be solved from userspace -- look into [real time linux](https://rt.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page), for an OS that's (relatively) easy to use and has soft-realtime capabilities. Still, probably not something you can tackle yourself, unfortunately. Use a CS grad student.

Comment: If GUI events and common operating systems are too slow or unreliable for your needs, Python might be the wrong programming language to start with.

Answer (score 23):

When people talk about real-time computing, what they mean is that the latency from an interrupt (most commonly set off by a timer) to application code handling that interrupt being run, is both small and predictable.  This then means that a control process can be run repeatedly at very precise time intervals or, as in your case, external events can be timed very precisely.  The variation in latency is usually called "jitter" - 1ms maximum jitter means that an interrupt arriving repeatedly will have a response latency that varies by at most 1ms.

"Small" and "predictable" are both relative terms and when people talk about real-time performance they might mean 1μs maximum jitter (people building inverters for power transmission care about this sort of performance, for instance) or they might mean a couple of milliseconds maximum jitter.  It all depends on the requirements of the application.

At any rate, Python is not likely to be the right tool for this job, for a few reasons:

- Python runs mostly on desktop operating systems.  Desktop operating systems impose a lower limit on the maximum jitter; in the case of Windows, it is several seconds.  Multiple-second events don't happen very often, every day or two, and you'd be unlucky to have one coincide with the thing you're trying to measure, but sooner or later it will happen; jitter in the several-hundred-milliseconds region happens more often, perhaps every hour, and jitter in the tens-of-milliseconds region is fairly frequent.  The numbers for desktop Linux are probably similar, though you can apply different compile-time options and patch sets to the Linux kernel to improve the situation - Google PREEMPT_RT_FULL.
- Python's stop-the-world garbage collector makes latency non-deterministic.  When Python decides it needs to run the garbage collector, your program gets stopped until it finishes.  You may be able to avoid this through careful memory management and carefully setting the garbage collector parameters, but depending on what libraries you are using, you may not, too.
- Other features of Python's memory management make deterministic latency difficult.  Most real-time systems avoid heap allocation (ie C's `malloc` or C++'s `new`) because the amount of time they take is not predictable.  Python neatly hides this from you, making it very difficult to control latency.  Again, using lots of those nice off-the-shelf libraries only makes the situation worse.
- In the same vein, it is essential that real-time processes have all their memory kept in physical RAM and not paged out to swap.  There is no good way of controlling this in Python, especially running on Windows (on Linux you might be able to fit a call to `mlockall` in somewhere, but any new allocation will upset things).

I have a more basic question though.  You don't say whether your button is a physical button or one on the screen.  If it's one on the screen, the operating system will impose an unpredictable amount of latency between the physical mouse button press and the event arriving at your Python application.  How will you account for this?  Without a more accurate way of measuring it, how will you even know whether it is there?

Comment: I know this is an old post, but in your 4th point you mentioned "(on Linux you might be able to fit a call to mlockall in somewhere, but any new allocation will upset things)", would you mind explaining why? I am looking to implement something similar and this raises a slight concern. Thanks!

Comment: This might be me misunderstanding `mlockall()` - I think there is an option to lock both current and future allocations in physical RAM, in which case future allocations would not upset it (as much - dynamic allocation is still non-deterministic, and gets worse as RAM fills up).

Answer (score 5):

Python is not, by purist's standards, a real-time language- it has too many libraries and functions to be bare-bones fast. If you're already going through an OS though, as opposed to an embedded system, you've already lost a lot of true real time capability. (When I hear "real time" I think the time it takes VHDL code to flow through the wires of an FPGA. Other people use it to mean "I hit a button and it does something that is, from my slow human perspective, instantaneous". I'll assume you're using the latter interpretation of real time.)

By stimulus display and button press detection I assume you mean you have something (for example) like a trial where you show a person an image and have them click a button to identify the image or confirm that they've seen it- perhaps to test reaction speed. Unless you're worried about accuracy down to the millisecond (which should be negligible compared to the time for a human reaction) you would be able to do a test like this using python. To work on the GUI, look into Tkinter: http://www.pythonware.com/library/tkinter/introduction/. To work on the timing between stimulus and a button press, look at the time docs: http://docs.python.org/library/time.html

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. I already have this thing pretty coded up, I just want to make it as accurate as possible. Do you have any inkling of what the lag might be? As for the size of the reaction time, it might take a subject around 600 ms to react to a presented word, but the effect we are looking at is probably going to be around 35-45 ms.

Comment: You can profile your code (http://docs.python.org/library/profile.html) to see what your lag is.  I'd think you'd want to compile some statistics on the time lag of your software to incorporate into the error margins of your results.

Comment: The wording here muds the waters again:  "bare bones fast". Realtime does not imply fast, only that there is a strict maximum response time for a a given event. Many systems are fast and many non-real time systems are faster than most real-time systems and yet can/will experience occasional unacceptable delays.

Answer (score 4):

Because you are trying to get a scientific measurement on a time delay in millisecond precision, I cannot recommend any process that is subject to time slicing on a general purpose computer.  Whether implemented in C, or Java, or Python, if it runs in a time-shared mode, then how can the result be verifiable?  You could be challenged to prove that the CPU never interrupted the process during a measurement, thereby distorting the results.

It sounds like you may need to construct a dedicated device for this purpose, with a clock circuit that ticks at a known rate and can measure the discrete number of ticks that occur between stimulus and response.  That device can then be controlled by software that has no such timing constraints.  Maybe you should post this question to the [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) exchange.

Without a dedicated device, you will have to develop truly real-time software that, it terms of modern operating systems, runs within the kernel and is not subject to task switching.  This is not easy to do, and it takes a lot of effort to get it right.  More time, I would guess, than you would spend building a dedicated software-controllable device for your purpose.

Comment: These problems are well-understood and there are well-known tools for handling them; you might start by googling 'process priority'.

Answer (score 4):

Most common operating systems' interrupts are variable enough to ruin timing in your experiment regardless of your programming language. Python adds it's own unreliability. Windows interrupts are especially bad. In Windows, most interrupts are serviced in about 4 milliseconds, but occasionally an interrupts last longer than 35 milliseconds! (Windows 7).

I would recommend trying the PsycoPy application to see if will work for you. It approaches the problem by trying to make the graphics card do the work in openGL, however some of it's code still runs outside the graphics card and is subject to the operating system's interrupts. Your existing python code may not be compatible with PsycoPy, but at least you would stay in Python. PsycoPy is especially good at showing visual stimulations without timing issues. See this page in their documentation to see how you would handle a button press: http://www.psychopy.org/api/event.html

To solve your problem the right way, you need a real-time operating system, such as LinuxRT or QNX.  You could try your python application in one of those to see if running python in a real-time environment is good enough, but even python introduces variability.  If python decides to garbage collect, you will have a glitch. Python itself isn't real time.

National Instruments sells a setup that allows you to program in real-time in a very easy-to-use programming language called LabviewRT.  LabviewRT pushing your code into an FPGA daughter card that operates in real time. It's expensive.

I strongly suggest you don't just minimize this problem, but **solve it**, otherwise, your reviewers will be uncomfortable.

Answer (score 2):

If you are running the Python code on Linux machine, make the kernel low latency (preemptive).
There is a flag for it when you compile the kernel.

Make sure that other processes running on the machine are minimum so they do not interrupt the kernel.

Assign higher task priority to your Python script.

Comment: and?!? how do you get read of non deterministic garbage collection?

Comment: By turning it off. It was stated that the system must be low-latency only for a round of like 50 tests and can then spend some time being less responsive. It's only constant soft real time behavior that's hard to achieve with a non-deterministic GC, as long as it is possible to temporarily shut it down.

Answer (score 1):

1. Run the python interpreter on a real time operating system or tweaked linux.
2. Shut down the garbage collector during the experiments and back on afterward.
3. Maybe actively trigger a garbage collection round after the end of an experiment.

Additionally, keep in mind that showing an image is not instantaneous. You must synchronize your experiment with your monitor's vertical retrace phase (the pause between transmitting the last line of a frame of the display's content and the first line of the next frame).

I would start the timer at the beginning of the vsync phase after transmission of the frame containing whatever candidates are supposed to react to.

And one would have to keep in mind that the image is going to be ast least partially visible a bit earlier than that for purposes of getting absolute reaction times as opppsed to just well comparable results with ~ half a frame of offset due to the non-instantaneous appearance of the monitor's contents (~10 ms @ 60Hz).