# Raspberry Pi Embedded application

Tags: linux-kernel, computer-vision, real-time, raspberry-pi3

I am developing a computer vision system to control orientation of two mirrors to track stimuli in field of view.We are sending coordinates to motor over network and trying to track as smoothly as possible.

I have two questions regarding this :

1.Is Python suitable for this kind of project . I have already coded it in Python and find it very easy to use.

2. I am running Raspbian on raspberry Pi but found that it's not a real time os. We are sending command every 20 ms to the server built on raspberry Pi. Should I switch to arduino or patch the Linux kernel for this application.

Comment: *"it's not a real time os"* -- You're confusing the distribution with the OS.  Linux is not a realtime OS.  There are "realtime" patches for the Linux kernel to make its response times more deterministic, but you should also evaluate the preemptive kernel, the various task & I/O schedulers, and high-resolution timers.  For #1 see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1402933/python-on-an-real-time-operation-system-rtos and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7079864/real-time-operating-via-python

Answer (score 0):

1. Python, combined with OpenCV, is one of the best candidates for this task.
2. As mentioned in the comment above, the "real-time" issue is OS related. I personally recommend an Arduino-based solution, even though that puts more burden on the hardware design. You could also check the new IoT solutions from Intel, they have a wide range of boards.

Comment: I am thinking of going with preemptive kernel